# Incrementation and addition in pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have written the following code and it works fine. But before I made changes i had entered a few statements which I expected would work but didn't. Just as a trial, i made changes and it worked. Please clarify what I was doing wrong. I am trying simple programs initially to make my understanding of Pointers better.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
        int i;
        char *instring,*outstring;
        char ch,p;
        instring = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
        outstring= (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter the string:");
        gets(instring);
        printf("Enter the character to be removed:");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(instring);i++)
        {
                if( *(instring+i) != ch)
                {
                *(outstring+i) = *(instring+i);  
                printf("%c",*(outstring+i));
                }
        }
```

Under if statement, I had written the following:

```
if(*(instring) != ch)
{
 *outstring = *instring;
 printf("%c",*(outstring));
 instring++;
 outstring++;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What didn't work about it? What were you expecting? What actually happened?

Comment: the problem is in *(instring) != ch, u can't compare 2 strings like that. see strcmp

Comment: Also I believe you want to increment the pointer instring and the pointer outstring, not the strings themselves. but without more info it's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @HoussemBdr He's comparing two chars, isn't he?

Comment: `instring = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char));` is better written as `instring=malloc(15);`. `*(outstring+i)` is better written as `outstring[i]`.  `gets(instring)` is better written as ***"NEVER USE gets()!!!"***.

Comment: fgets() instead of gets()?

Comment: Well if my memory serves, two characters can be compared this way but strings cant be compared using `==`, for that you have to use strcmp/

Comment: @UmerFarooq: He's not comparing strings. (And you mean `==`, not `=`.)

Comment: `it works fine` Doubtful

Comment: Doesn't he need some conditional to not advance outstring if the char IS found?  @Keith cool shouting! :)

Comment: Repeat after me: Never use `gets()`.  **NEVER USE `gets()`!**

Comment: @AdamRosenfield "Never use gets()!".. Okay, but why not? What do I use instead?? Please explain.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for suggesting a better way for allocating memory. Its much more simple this way. And why has the usage of gets() been discouraged? Really need to know. Thanks! :)

Comment: I got what is to be used instead!! :)

Comment: [comp.Lang.c.FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) question 12.23. And the `gets` function was removed the language by the 2011 ISO C standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by not working, but if your non-working function looked like this:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(instring);i++)
{
    if(*(instring) != ch)
    {
        *outstring = *instring;
        printf("%c",*(outstring));
        instring++;
        outstring++;
    }
}
```

Then it looks like the problem is that you are only incrementing `instring` if it's current character doesn't match ch.  So if `instring's` current character **does** match `ch`, you will loop forever and the process will hang.

Also, if all you want to do is print out the string without the character to be removed, you don't need outstring.  Just do e.g.

```
 printf("%c",*(instring));
```

On the other hand if you also want to store the string in outstring with the character removed, you can't increment the pointers in tandem like you are doing.  Because when you hit the character to be removed, you want to increment the instring pointer to move past it, but not increment the outstring pointer since you haven't added anything to that string.

Comment: "you want to increment the instring pointer to move past it, but not increment the outstring pointer since you haven't added anything to that string." Yea, now I realize it. Cleared my doubts. I got what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It does work. But you loose both strings (pointers to them)
Try to store pointers to the beginning of both strings in another two pointers (char*) and then do your cycle.
And at the end, print the pointers you stored before - because they still point to your strings. When you increment pointers `instring` and `outstring`, they don't point to your strings anymore - they point to the very end of these strings.

Play with it a little bit more and you'll see :)

edit: Well, no, I've been writing faster then reading, sorry. Your (another) problem is even sooner - comparison. You are comparing `instring` with character and you change it only if condition is true. So you are comparing the same thing over and over and over.

It's tough to tell, what your problem really is.

Comment: "When you increment pointers instring and outstring, they don't point to your strings anymore - they point to the very end of these strings." That cleared so many doubts! Thanks! :)